# How to force shutdown a android phone? (ZS570KL specifically)

Tags: shutdown

My phone fell several days ago, and the screen didn't display anything now.

The model is ASUS Zenfone 3 Deluxe (ZS570KL), and I didn't root, flash recovery, or turn on debugging mode on it. The Android version is 8.0.

I've talked to customer service of phone manufacturer and was told that there's no more spare screen.

I tried to shut it down, but long pressing power button can only make it reboot. Is there any way that can force shutdown the phone?

Comment: Your device supports HDMI over USB-C, so you can connect it to an external display.  You may want to reach out to repair companies that will likely have an inventory of the screen, such as [U Break I Fix](https://www.ubreakifix.com/).

Comment: Why don't you let the battery discharge fully? It would do the job.

Comment: JW0914: My device doesn't support HDMI over USB-C.
@Firelord: How do I know it is fully discharged?